# Cant get firebase image URL from storage right after uploading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, url, storage

I'm using firebase storage for an app so that I can store images I want to be displayed in a popup window. Right now I can reference the image but I'm unable to get the `URL` for the image using `getDownloadURL()`.

I've tried everything but can't seem to get the URL and only get errors in the console saying `Error: Reference.push failed: the first argument contains undefined in property 'markers.imageURL.i'", AND " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (HTTP/2.0 404)`

Anyone know why?

Heres a snippet of my code. imageFURLY is what doesn't return the URL.

```js
document.getElementById('infowindowSubmit').addEventListener('click', function (event, imageFURL) {
                    // This function saves the newly created marker and the infowindow information when
                    //the 'Submit' button is clicked.

                    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
                    var file = fileInput.files[0];
                    //Create storage ref
                    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('markerpics/' + file.name);
                    var task = storageRef.put(file);
                    
                    console.log('storageRef ', storageRef)
                    imageFURL = storageRef;
                    console.log('imageFURL ', imageFURL);
                    //Upload file
                    imageFURLY = imageFURL.getDownloadURL();
                    console.log('imageFURLY ', imageFURLY);


                    //Variables that store data inputted in infowindow
                    var postName = document.getElementById('formName');
                    var postNameF = postName.value;
                    var postMessage = document.getElementById('formMessage');
                    var postMessageF = postMessage.value;
                    var postImageRef = imageFURLY;
                    console.log('postImageRef - URL: ', postImageRef);
                    var latitude = location.lat(location);
                    var longitude = location.lng(location);


                    //Closes markers open infowindow
                    largeInfowindow.close(map, marker);
                    //Sets markers infowindow to NEW content
                    console.log('Setting infowindow content!! ');
                    largeInfowindow.setContent('<div>' + '<div>Name: ' + postNameF + '</div><br>' + '<div>Message: ' + postMessageF + '</div><br>' + '<div>Image: ' + '</div>' + '<img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" src="' + postImageRef + '" alt="Mountain View">' + '<br>' + '</div>');
                    console.log('Set infowindow content!! ');
                    largeInfowindow.open(map, marker);
                    // Make sure the marker property is cleared if the infowindow is closed.
                    largeInfowindow.addListener('closeclick', function () {
                        largeInfowindow.marker = null;
                    });
```

Comment: does the variable `file` contain what you expect?

Comment: Yes. The code does what i expect until the line that says 'imageFURLY = imageFURL.getDownloadURL();
                    console.log('imageFURLY ', imageFURLY);' File gives me what i expect and even imageFURL does. But imageFURLY doesnt. I was thinking it has something to do with JS running code all at once but im honestly not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm willing to bet you're trying to get the URL of something that doesn't exist yet.

```
document.getElementById('infowindowSubmit').addEventListener('click', function (event, imageFURL) {
// This function saves the newly created marker and the infowindow information when
//the 'Submit' button is clicked.

var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var file = fileInput.files[0];
//Create storage ref
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('markerpics/' + file.name);
```

All fine so far

```
var task = storageRef.put(file);
```

That's deferred. `task` is a promise.

```
console.log('storageRef ', storageRef)
imageFURL = storageRef;
console.log('imageFURL ', imageFURL);
//Upload file
imageFURLY = imageFURL.getDownloadURL();
```

`put` hasn't been executed yet, but you're calling `getDownloadURL()`. Therefore, it's not there yet! And you get a 404.

Here's how you fix it:

```
document.getElementById('infowindowSubmit').addEventListener('click', function (event, imageFURL) {
// This function saves the newly created marker and the infowindow information when
//the 'Submit' button is clicked.

var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var file = fileInput.files[0];
//Create storage ref
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('markerpics/' + file.name);

var task = storageRef.put(file);
task.then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log('storageRef ', storageRef)
    imageFURL = storageRef;
    console.log('imageFURL ', imageFURL);
    //Upload file
    imageFURLY = imageFURL.getDownloadURL();
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Yes!! That makes sense. Working now and thanks for explaining my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

```
let file = await bucket.upload(fromFilePath, {destination: toFilePath});
const trimUrl = file[0].metatata.mediaLink
```